# $Y$ is a proper closed subspace and $||f_0|| = 1$ and $d(f_0, Y ) = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let 
>   $$
> X = \{f \in C[0,1] : f(0) = 0\},\quad Y = \{f \in X : \int_0^1 f(t)dt = 0\}.$$ Prove that $Y$ is a proper closed subspace and $ \|f_0\|= 1$ and $d(f_0, Y ) = 1$.

I am getting a feeling to use Riesz Lemma, but unable to proceed. Need some hints.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_0$?

Comment: Please update your question and address what is $f_0$.

Comment: I have given an answer.  Please check.

Answer (score 2):

The closedness of $Y$ is simple. If $\{f_n\}\subset Y$ and $f_n\to f$ in $X$, then $\int_0^1 f(t)dt
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_n(t)dt=0$. Also, we can show the closedness of $Y$ by observing that $F(u)=\int_0^1 u(t)dt$ is a continuous linear functional and $Y=Ker{F}$, because the null space of every continuous functional is closed.

For the second problem, I guess you want us to find $f_0\in X$ such that $\|f\|=d(f_0,Y)=1$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**But, such function doesn't exist.** We can recall  the following result, which can be found in page 24 of  H. Brezis's "Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDEs". It can be proved by Hahn-Banach Theorem.

> Let $u\in X$ . Then it holds that $d(u,Y)=|\int_0^1 u(t) dt|$.

In view of this result, we know that if $f_0$ exits, then it has to satisfy 
$$
|\int_0^1 f_0(t)dx|=1=\|f_0\|.
$$
The only continuous function satisfies the property above is $f\equiv\pm 1$, which is not in $X$, because $f_0(0)\neq 0$

PS:

> Let us consider a general linear approximation problem $\inf_{u\in M}\|u-b\|$, where $M$ is a subspace of a Banach space $X$, and $b\in X$. Then we have
>   $$
> \inf_{u\in M}\|u-b\|=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1,\,\, f\in M^0}|\langle f, b\rangle|,
> $$ 
>   where $M^0:=\{f\in X', f(x)=0 \,\forall\,x\in M\}$. The right-hand side of the equation is called "the dual problem " of the original approximation problem. The result above is only a special case of this general result.

Comment: +1....... By elementary means (without Hahn-Banach), for a Banach space $B$ and $0\ne G\in B^*$ and $Y=G^{-1}\{0\}$ we have (i). $Y$ is of co-dimension $1$ in $B$, which implies ... (ii). $\forall x\in B\;( |G(x)=\|G\|\cdot d(x, Y)),$... and (iii). $\forall x\in B$ \ $Y \;\exists y\in Y\;(\|x-y\|=d(x,Y)) \iff $ $\exists x\in B \setminus Y\;\exists y\in Y\; (\|x-y\|=d(x,Y))\iff$ $\iff  \exists x\in B$ \ Y$\; (|G(x)=\|G\|\cdot \|x\|).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It also works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are working with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

Define $\phi : X \to X$ as $\phi(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$. $\phi$ is obviously linear, and it is also bounded:

$$|\phi(f)| = \left|\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right| \le \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx \le \int_0^1 \|f\|_\infty\,dx = \|f\|_\infty$$

Thus, $\phi$ is continuous and $Y = \phi^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed as a preimage of a closed set under a continuous function.

Now I'm assuming you wish to find $f_0 \in X$ such that $\|f_0\|_\infty = 1$ and $d(f_0, Y) = 1$.

**Note: The following is not correct since $1 \notin X$**

Take $f_0 \equiv 1$. We obviously have $\|f_0\|_\infty = 1$ and since $d(f_0,0) = 1$, we get $d(f_0, Y)\le 1$.

To show that $d(f_0, Y)\ge 1$ assume there exists $f \in X$ such that $\|f - f_0\|_\infty < 1$. This would mean that there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists an interval $I \subseteq [0,1]$ containing $x_0$ such that $f|_I > 0$.

We have:

$$0 = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx =\underbrace{\int\limits_I f(x)\,dx}_{>0} + \int\limits_{[0,1]\setminus I} f(x)\,dx$$

Therefore, $f$ has to be negative at some $x_1 \in [0,1]\setminus I$ which implies $\|f - f_0\|_\infty > 1$, which is a contradiction. Such a function $f$ cannot exist, so $d(f_0, Y) \ge 1$.

Thus, $d(f_0, Y) = 1$.

Comment: $f_0\equiv 1$ can't in $X$ becaue $f_0(0)\neq 0$

Comment: You can check my answer. Such function does not exit

Comment: @Icesea You're right.